# Start a local copy of an application from network

Tags: c#, windows, network-share

I have a seemingly simple question. (I did check this: [process Working Directory from network / shared directory to local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281702/process-working-directory-from-network-shared-directory-to-local), but it's not exactly what I need).

I am developing an app that will reside on the network and be accessible by everyone in our company.
The problem starts when I want to update the executable with a newer version while someone has it open.

I was thinking check a predefined local location (like user's appdata folder or something).
See if the executable is there. If it isn't, copy from network to a local and start there.
If already there, check for assembly version and if the one on the network is newer, then update the local copy.

Would this be the best way of doing this?
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: There's probably a better solution, but the simplest thing would be to have the application, upon startup, check if it is launched from the network share and copy itself locally. Then spawn a new copy of itself from the local version. This might be easier if you split it into a "launcher" and the real app.